# Audio does not play in Android Q

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play audio from SD Card in Android Q, unfortunately the audio player is not working on Android Q but it works perfectly in Android version pre Q like Android Pie. 
Here is my code

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(getUrl));

mediaPlayer.prepare();

mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);

mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());


seekBarHint2.setText(convertDuration(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));

mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Its not like a crash of your app. But MediaPlayer has a lot of bugs thats why google made Exoplayer. Please switch to Exoplayer here https://exoplayer.dev/

Comment: To play audio in android it is better to use exoplayer. If you want some help in exoplayer, i can give you an sample code how to use exoplayer

Comment: Issue resolved by adding this android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in the application tag(AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: thanks for the comment on the legacy external storage request, it fixed my media player refactor to andoridx.